# Implementing "select on focus" behavior for an Eclipse Text control

Tags: java, eclipse, textbox, swt, eclipse-3.6

#### Goal

I'm trying to implement "select on focus" behavior for an Eclipse [`Text`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html) control:

- When the control is **already** focused:

  - clicking and dragging behaves normally

- When the control is **not** focused:

  - clicking and dragging to select text behaves normally
  - clicking without selecting text will select all text
  - giving focus using the keyboard will select all text

#### Problem

- Simply selecting all text for `SWT.FocusIn` doesn't select text when focusing by mouse click.
- `SWT.FocusIn` is fired ***before*** `SWT.MouseDown`, so there's no way to tell if the control already had focus when the user presses the mouse down.

#### Questions

1. Why does Eclipse fire the events in that order? That doesn't make any sense to me. Is it a restriction of some supported OS?
2. Is there some workaround I can use to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone in #eclipse linked me to an Eclipse bug raised a long time ago: [Can't use focus listener to select all text](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=46059)

Using one of the suggestions there, I came up with the following solution (works in Windows, untested on other platforms):

```
/**
 * This method adds select-on-focus functionality to a {@link Text} component.
 * 
 * Specific behavior:
 *  - when the Text is already focused -> normal behavior
 *  - when the Text is not focused:
 *    -> focus by keyboard -> select all text
 *    -> focus by mouse click -> select all text unless user manually selects text
 * 
 * @param text
 */
public static void addSelectOnFocusToText(Text text) {
  Listener listener = new Listener() {

    private boolean hasFocus = false;
    private boolean hadFocusOnMousedown = false;

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
      switch(e.type) {
        case SWT.FocusIn: {
          Text t = (Text) e.widget;

          // Covers the case where the user focuses by keyboard.
          t.selectAll();

          // The case where the user focuses by mouse click is special because Eclipse,
          // for some reason, fires SWT.FocusIn before SWT.MouseDown, and on mouse down
          // it cancels the selection. So we set a variable to keep track of whether the
          // control is focused (can't rely on isFocusControl() because sometimes it's wrong),
          // and we make it asynchronous so it will get set AFTER SWT.MouseDown is fired.
          t.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              hasFocus = true;
            }
          });

          break;
        }
        case SWT.FocusOut: {
          hasFocus = false;
          ((Text) e.widget).clearSelection();

          break;
        }
        case SWT.MouseDown: {
          // Set the variable which is used in SWT.MouseUp.
          hadFocusOnMousedown = hasFocus;

          break;
        }
        case SWT.MouseUp: {
          Text t = (Text) e.widget;
          if(t.getSelectionCount() == 0 && !hadFocusOnMousedown) {
            ((Text) e.widget).selectAll();
          }

          break;
        }
      }
    }

  };

  text.addListener(SWT.FocusIn, listener);
  text.addListener(SWT.FocusOut, listener);
  text.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, listener);
  text.addListener(SWT.MouseUp, listener);
}
```

Comment: Glad you found your answer. Will bookmark this for future use.